# Using Promise.all on Firestore query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I have an HTTP Cloud function that queries and updates document in Firestore. Basically what the function does is select all vehicles from a collection, calculate energy usage for each vehicle of different time ranges (24 hour, 12 hour and 6 hour), aggregates the results and update another collection with the result.

This is how my Firestore is structured.

```
vehicles (collection)
----vehicle (document)
    -----telemetry (subcollection) this is where the energy values will come from
```

This is my script so far, I am using Promise.all to combine all queries for different time ranges, compute for the energy usage of each vehicle and add it up to a running total, but this doesn't work well.

```
exports.getAllEnergyUsage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const store = admin.firestore()
  store.collection('vehicles').get().then(snapshot => {

    let allYesterdayResult = 0;
    let allTwelveHourResult = 0;
    let allSixHourResult = 0;

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const data_dict = doc.data();
      let queryResults = [];
      const vehicle = data_dict.vehicle_name;
      const vehicleRef = store.collection('vehicles').doc(vehicle);
      const today = new Date();
      const yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - (24*60*60*1000));
      const twelveHours = new Date(today.getTime() - (12*60*60*1000));
      const sixHours = new Date(today.getTime() - (6*60*60*1000));

      // console.log(today, sixHours);

      var queries = [
        vehicleRef.collection('telemetry').where('time_stamp', '<', today).where('time_stamp', '>', yesterday).get(),
        vehicleRef.collection('telemetry').where('time_stamp', '<', today).where('time_stamp', '>', twelveHours).get(),
        vehicleRef.collection('telemetry').where('time_stamp', '<', today).where('time_stamp', '>', sixHours).get()
      ]

      for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        queryResults.push(
          queries[i]
        )
      }

      Promise.all(queryResults)
        .then(snapShot=> {

          const yesterdayResult = result => getEnergy(result);
          const twelveHourResult = result => getEnergy(result);
          const sixHourResult = result => getEnergy(result);

          allYesterdayResult += yesterdayResult(snapShot[0])
          allTwelveHourResult += twelveHourResult(snapShot[1])
          allSixHourResult +=sixHourResult(snapShot[2])


          console.log("Done updating vehicle ", vehicle)
          // return res.send({"Result" : "Successful!"})
        }).catch(reason => {
          console.log(reason)
          // return res.send({"Result" : "Error!"})
      });



    })
    var vehicle_summary = {
      yesterday : allYesterdayResult,
      twelveHourResult : allTwelveHourResult,
      sixHourResult : allSixHourResult,
      timestamp : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

    }
    console.log(vehicle_summary);
    store.collection('vehicles_summary').doc('energy').set(vehicle_summary);
  })

return res.send({"Result" : "Successful!"})


});
```

This is the result, this would not give me the summary of Energy Usage that I want because from what I understand the promises are still running but the function already returned(Please correct me if I am wrong).

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {"Result":"Successful!"}
info: { yesterday: 0,
  twelveHourResult: 0,
  sixHourResult: 0,
  timestamp: FieldValue {} }
info: Running loop on each SnapShot=======
info: Running loop on each SnapShot=======
Running loop on each SnapShot=======
Done updating vehicle  Vehicle2
Running loop on each SnapShot=======
Running loop on each SnapShot=======
info: Running loop on each SnapShot=======
Done updating vehicle  Vehicle1
info: Running loop on each SnapShot=======
info: Running loop on each SnapShot=======
Running loop on each SnapShot=======
info: Done updating vehicle  Vehicle3
```

Any idea how I can make this happen? I came from Python and just learning node.js, I am still thinking very synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a result before *any* of the async work is complete:

```
return res.send({"Result" : "Successful!"})
```

After this response is sent, this terminates the function.  There is no guarantee that any async work after this point will complete the way you expect.

For HTTP functions, you should *only* send a response *after* all the async work is fully complete.

Comment: How do I determine whether all the async work is done? from my code, for each document, I am running a Promise.all.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need a single promise that represents **all** the work.  Collect them all into an array and use Promise.all on the entire list.  Again: You're currently not actually waiting until any of the work is complete before returning the response.  Try simplifying your work, getting that right first, then complicating it to meet the full requirements.

Comment: the problem with putting all queries in one promise. Is that I have no idea how to identify which query is 24,12 or 6 hour. Because I have to summarize results based on those time ranges. And `promise.all` as far as I know only accepts array, it would be nice if I could use objects and passed it to `promise.all` like this.`{"24_h":query, "12_h":query, "6_h":query}` so when the `promise.all` finishes, I can refer to the key to determine time range.

Comment: @essramos Promise.all will return the resolved queries in the same order they were added to the array